# Como faço para desativar o terceiro e quarto EditText caso o primeiro não esteja preenchido?

Tags: java, android

Tenho três EditText e preciso verificar se o primeiro EditText está vazio e se o segundo EditText também está vazio.

Caso Afirmativo eu devo desativar o terceiro EditText.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Certo mas para fazer a verificação você irá clicar em um botão ?

Comment: não. O cara aqui disse que a partir do momento que digitar um caractere no primeiro EditText eu já posso habilitar o terceiro EditText para o cara escrever....

Comment: mas parece que é mais difícil né

Answer (score 1):

Um caso simples que possa sacionar seu problema seria, caso ao clicar em cima dos editText, ele faz essas verificações e validações para você

```
     editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String editText1_text = editText1.getText().toString();
            String editText2_text = editText2.getText().toString();

            if(editText1_text == null && editText2_text == null)
                editText3_text.setVisibility(GONE);
            else if(editText1_text != null && editText2_text != null)
                editText3_text.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

    });

editText2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String editText1_text = editText1.getText().toString();
        String editText2_text = editText2.getText().toString();

        if(editText1_text == null && editText2_text == null)
            editText3_text.setVisibility(GONE);
        else if(editText1_text != null && editText2_text != null)
            editText3_text.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Comment: No toque do EditText né? Vou fazer aqui nunca tentei dessa forma...

Comment: Isso, ao tocar o ediText voce faz a verificação, mas neste caso em especifico você irá habiltiar o terceiro editText caso os dois outros forem diferentes de nulo =)

Comment: você trabalha com android também?

Comment: Sim trabalho com android hehe

Comment: é testei ão deu certo...

Comment: vou tentar com textChanged...

Comment: tmb é uma opção =) TextChanged verifica toda vez que foi realizado alguma operação no EditText

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63939/discussion-between-matheus-and-aline).